# Ubuntu 22.04 near 100% CPU usage all cores

Tags: 22.04, cpu, system

I have just installed the most recent stable release of Ubuntu (22.04) on a new  computer. It is a clean install on new hardware.

As soon as I started to use the PC it is using 98-100% of 6 cores at all times. The remaining 2 cores slowly ramp up to near 100% usage too. This is when the computer is idle. RAM usage is low (less than 10% of total capacity).

I checked the processes and nothing is showing as using the CPU beyond 1-3% when it is actually being used. But the resource monitor shows high usage, the computer shows signs of high CPU usage and other programs are showing the effect.

In case there is some build incompatibility (not sure why that would be the case but it is possible) the system has:

AMD Ryzen 7 5800x

Corsair vengance

2x 32GB RAM

Radeon RX6700XT

Samsung 500Gb M.2 NVME

I have tried swapping out for known good RAM.The usual have you tried turning off and on again. I have run the bash line update. The BIOS has been updated.

Picture of system monitor results.

Comment: Are there any background processes such as Docker that may account for system resource usage? 

Comment: Thank you . Running $ps aux does not show anything usual. Is there another way to find processes using a lot of capacity?

Comment: My tool of choice is `glances`, but `top` and `htop` are more common tools to see where processing power is being used. If you have some I/O constraints, that can also seriously affect system performance. This is generally seen on lower-power devices, though 

Comment: Nothign more than Chrome using about 5% of the CPU. I might just role back to the previous version and update again later. That should solve the CPU problem and a bunch of others at the same time. Simplest solution. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Whatever, any processor use should show up in tools like top or htop. Perhaps it is the indexing of Tracker, in which case the activity will end after the indexing.